# Why $a_i b_m c_n\left(\delta_{m k} \delta_{n i}-\delta_{m i} \delta_{n k}\right) \mathbf{e}_k=a_n b_m c_n \mathbf{e}_m-a_m b_m c_n \mathbf{e}_n$?

Tags: permutations, index-notation, kronecker-delta

I am stuck in an intermediate step.

> In order to evaluate the product of the Levi-Civita symbols, we use the identity
> $$
> \epsilon_{m n j} \epsilon_{i j k}=\delta_{m k} \delta_{n i}-\delta_{m i} \delta_{n k}
> $$
> and the properties of the Kronecker delta functions. Thus, we obtain
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \mathbf{a} \times(\mathbf{b} \times \mathbf{c}) &=\epsilon_{m n j} \epsilon_{i j k} a_i b_m c_n \mathbf{e}_k \\
> &=a_i b_m c_n\left(\delta_{m k} \delta_{n i}-\delta_{m i} \delta_{n k}\right) \mathbf{e}_k \\
> &=a_n b_m c_n \mathbf{e}_m-a_m b_m c_n \mathbf{e}_n \\
> &=\left(b_m \mathbf{e}_m\right)\left(c_n a_n\right)-\left(c_n \mathbf{e}_n\right)\left(a_m b_m\right) \\
> &=\mathbf{b}(\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{c})-\mathbf{c}(\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b})
> \end{aligned}
> $$

http://people.uncw.edu/hermanr/qm/Levi_Civita.pdf

Comment: just replace $k,i$ with $m,n$ in the first and then $k,i$ with $n,m$ in the second i.e. use the definition of $\delta_{xy}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have,

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{a} \times(\mathbf{b} \times \mathbf{c}) &=\epsilon_{m n j} \epsilon_{i j k} a_i b_m c_n \mathbf{e}_k \\
&=a_i b_m c_n\left(\delta_{m k} \delta_{n i}-\delta_{m i} \delta_{n k}\right) \mathbf{e}_k \\
&=a_i b_m c_n\delta_{m k} \delta_{n i}\mathbf{e}_k-a_i b_m c_n\delta_{m i} \delta_{n k} \mathbf{e}_k 
\end{aligned}
$$
Now recall that this expression includes bunch of summations. In the the first term, $\delta_{m k} \delta_{n i}$ makes all other terms zero unless $m=k$ and $n=i$. So all that remains is $a_n b_m c_n \mathbf{e}_m$. Similarly the second term $\delta_{m i} \delta_{n k}$ makes all other terms zero unless $m=i$ and $n=k$. So the secomd term is $a_m b_m c_n \mathbf{e}_n.$ That gives you

$$
\begin{aligned}
a_i b_m c_n\delta_{m k} \delta_{n i}\mathbf{e}_k-a_i b_m c_n\delta_{m i} \delta_{n k} \mathbf{e}_k&=a_n b_m c_n \mathbf{e}_m-a_m b_m c_n \mathbf{e}_n \\
&=\left(b_m \mathbf{e}_m\right)\left(c_n a_n\right)-\left(c_n \mathbf{e}_n\right)\left(a_m b_m\right) \\
&=\mathbf{b}(\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{c})-\mathbf{c}(\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b})
\end{aligned}
$$